# image File type associations and sorting

Tags: file-type

Ubuntu 14.04. Just upgraded from 12
When downloading images from camera (RAW+JPG basic) In file viewer it associates both NEF and JPG as image types.My workflow first action was to separate Jpgs into a sub folder. To do this I used to sort on type. 14.04 seems to see them both as image types now tho.  So I cant simply sort, highlight all JPG and move to another folder.

Is there a way to associate NEF with a different "Type". so I can sort again using this technique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the NEF file association in `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`, open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

Look for a line containing `image/x-nikon-nef` and delete only this line.

Then restart your system/session to filter by type as expected.

Comment: ahh thats where they live thanks. Just thinking,Is it breaking the "system" to create an association to a new type ie RAWimage

Comment: I don't think so if the new association type does not overwrite an existing one. If my answer helped, could you please accept it? thanks.